# How to read from std.in if the length of the input is not define

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm having problems with reading input from standard input in java using Scanner. I need to read the user input and put it in a dynamic array. Here's an example of the input:

```
4 6
2 3
4 8
9 5
```

And my code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

List<int[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();

int[] couple = new int[2];
int current = 0;
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
     if (current == 2) {
        temp.add(couple);
        current = 0;
        couple = new int[2];
     }
      couple[current] = scan.nextInt();
      current++;
}
scan.close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right, but you are not adding the last pair to the list. You can fix this problem by adding this code after the loop:

```
if (current == 2) {
    temp.add(couple);
}
```

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/CjzvyL)

Your approach is not ideal, though: rather than reading one integer at a time, you could read them in pairs, like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (!scan.hasNextInt()) break;
    int first = scan.nextInt();
    if (!scan.hasNextInt()) break;
    int second = scan.nextInt();
    temp.add(new int[] { first, second });
}
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/dxmCPW)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spaces between integers while typing the input? If so, then it would be a problem because spaces are chars or strings rather than integers.

Comment: Scannner has a special method to parse only numbers from a string. So no, spaces are not the problem. The problem is when to stop reading from stdin. Look at the solution from user @dasblinkenlight .